# Returning sqlite transaction with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite

I'm trying to create a service with angularjs that execute a query on a sqlite db and then returns if the query has been executed or if has occurred an error.
but the function always returns null because it return the variable r before the transaction has finished.

how can i return if the query has been executed or not?
Thanks

```
 this.Sql = function (query) {
        var db = connect(dbName);
        var r = null;

        db.transaction(function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(query, [],
                function (tx, result) {
                    r = "ok";
                },
                function (error) {
                    r = "error";
                });
        });

        return r;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You move your return into the promise.

```
this.Sql = function (query) {
var db = connect(dbName);
var r = null;

db.transaction(function (transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql(query, [],
        function (tx, result) {
            r = "ok";
            return r;
        },
        function (error) {
            r = "error";
            return r;
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I've already tried that but still it returns null when I call the function this way         var b = sqliteService.Sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ciao(a,b)");